# Transforming multiple object messed up onHover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, transform

When i try to place different divs with same class over each other, then the onHover is not working correctly when hovered upon.

In my jsfiddle you can try to hover over the green part: this will not change the curcus to "pointer"

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bh6n7v3n/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner_content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 50vw;
}

.content{
    height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
    position: relative;

    transform: rotateX(65deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-44deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(65deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-44deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(65deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-44deg);
  transform: rotateX(65deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-44deg);

  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.inner_content{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background:green;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var svgArray = $(".wrapper");

    var startValue = 50;
    var interval = 20;
    var startTranslationValue = startValue - (Math.ceil((svgArray.length-1)/2)*interval);

    for (var i = 0; i <= svgArray.length - 1; i++) {
        svgArray.eq(i).css('transform', 'translateX(-50%) translateY(-' + startTranslationValue + '%)'); 
        startTranslationValue += interval;
    }
});
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because your wrapper is in front of your inside div, blocking the hover state.

Try with this css:

```
.wrapper{
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content{
  pointer-events: auto;
}
/* This css just to see the hover state */
.content:hover{
  background: red;
}
```

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/jurdkyz4/

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the contents of the divs are overlapping, and you can't tell which div is being hovered upon.

I changed the code a little bit to make the '`.innercontent`' outside of the cluster, and as you can see when you hover over it, you get a `pointer` cursor:

```
.inner_content{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background:green;
  margin: 420px 50px 50px 50px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bh6n7v3n/1/

Comment: But my point is that it should be "hoverable" (cursor changing to pointer), even when the 'innercontent' is overlapped.

When i'm hovering over the innercontent, i'm probably hovering over another red 'content'. this should also then change my cursor.